# RegEx to convert number to comma separated numbers with optional two decimal places

Tags: regex, oracle, numbers, decimal

I am looking for a regular expression which will convert any amount value like `123/123.34/12345.99` will convert to a comma separated value like `123/123.34/12,345.99`. I am going to use this regular expression in Oracle.

I do not want to use TO_CHAR function. I need a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using to_char and its various features instead.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(-10000,'L99G999D99MI') "Amount" from dual
```

Comment: Brian I am looking for a regular expression. TO_CHAR will not serve my purpose. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Now you have two problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the syntax is in Oracle, but this worked for me in VSCode:
Replace

```
(\d{3})(?=\d)
```

With

```
$1,
```